# Trouble With Inserting An Image into Overleaf LaTeX

Tags: graphics, overleaf

I am currently writing TeX on Overleaf.
I need to insert an image of a trapezoid.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{systeme}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/genericname/Desktop/} }

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{trapezoid.png}
\end{document}
```

This is not working even though I know there is a .png file named `trapezoid` on my desktop. I am using overleaf to write this, so I am not sure if this would make a difference.

The error message says, "Package pdftex.def Error: File `trapezoid.png' not found."

Comment: As Francesco says, Overleaf cannot access files that are stored locally on your computer, so you have to upload them to Overleaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to upload the image on your overleaf project (Project - Files - upload...). Then you should write in the `.tex` file simply

```
\includegraphics{trapezoid.png}
```